# Simple UML Diagram...is this layout correct?

Tags: java, uml

I'm creating a UML diagram for the first time for an intro to Java course. I'm having trouble figuring out whether my classes are pointing to each other correctly.

Is the Guitar class supposed to be pointing to the test class? Also, should the Guitar class be to the left of the test class? Any pointers are much appreciated, thanks.

[image]
[My UML diagram hosted on ImageShack](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/1446/e7o.png)
(I don't have enough ref points to insert the image)

Code is below

```
package guitartest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guitar {

// Declare variables 
private int numberOfStrings;
private String stringName;
private boolean isTuned;
private boolean isPlaying;
private boolean isPlucking;


// Construct a guitar and set boolean fields to "false"
public Guitar(){
    this.isTuned = false;
    this.isPlaying = false;
    this.isPlucking = false;
}   // end constructor


// Prompt user to enter number of strings 
public int getNumberOfStrings() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Loop continues until a positive integer is entered
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter number of strings in integer format");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Error! That's not a number!");
            sc.next();
        }    // end while
        numberOfStrings = sc.nextInt();
     }    // end do-while loop
     while (numberOfStrings <= 0); 
    return numberOfStrings;
}   // end method getNumberOfStrings

// Prompt user to enter string names
public String getStringName() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Loop continues until all strings are named
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter string name"); 
        // Error if input is not a character
        while (!sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z]")) {
            System.out.println("Error! That's not a character!");
            sc.next();
         }
        stringName = sc.next();
    }   // end for loop
    return stringName;
}   // end method getStringName

// Verifies tuning status
public boolean tuneInstrument(){
    return isTuned;
}   // end method tuneInstrument

// Tune guitar
public void setTuned(boolean isTuned) {
    this.isTuned = isTuned;
}   // end method setTuned

// Verifies instrument is playing
public boolean playInstrument(){
    return isPlaying;
}   // end method playInstrument

// 
public void startPlayingInstrument(){
    isPlaying = true;
}   // end method startPlayingInstrument

public boolean pluckInstrument(){
    return isPlucking;
}   // end method pluckInstrument

public void startPlucking(){
    isPlucking = true;
}   // end method startPlucking

// Stop instrument
public void stopInstrument(){
    isPlaying = false;
}   // end method stopInstrument

}   // end class Guitar
```

The test class follows:

```
package guitartest;

import java.util.Scanner;
// Scanner is in the java.util package

public class GuitarTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create 10 guitar objects
    Guitar[] guitar = new Guitar[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < guitar.length; i++){
        guitar[i] = new Guitar();


    // Call methods in Guitar class
    guitar[i].getNumberOfStrings(); 
    guitar[i].getStringName();

    System.out.println("Is the guitar tuned? " + guitar[i].tuneInstrument());
    System.out.println("Guitar is being tuned. Please wait...");
    guitar[i].setTuned(true);
    System.out.println("Is the guitar tuned? " + guitar[i].tuneInstrument());

    System.out.println("Is the guitar playing? " + guitar[i].playInstrument());
    System.out.println("Please wait for guitar to play...");
    guitar[i].startPlayingInstrument();
    System.out.println("Is the guitar playing? " + guitar[i].playInstrument());

    System.out.println("Is the guitar being plucked? " + guitar[i].pluckInstrument());
    System.out.println("Please wait for guitar to be plucked...");
    guitar[i].startPlucking();
    System.out.println("The guitar is playing and being plucked. " + guitar[i].pluckInstrument());

    System.out.println("Stopping guitar from playing...");
    guitar[i].stopInstrument();
    System.out.println("Is the guitar playing? " + guitar[i].playInstrument());
    }   // end for loop

}   // end method main


}   // end class GuitarTest
```

Comment: Why the Guitar array?

Comment: Your Guitar class should have no user interface code. That code should be elsewhere such as in the main method of the GuitarTest tester class.

Comment: Thanks for the critiques. My project description requires that I create 10 instances of an object (to demonstrate that I comprehend how to create and use an array, I suppose).

Comment: Would it be appropriate to move the scanner and loops for the getNumberOfStrings and getStringName methods to the main method of the GuitarTest class? I'm confused about where to put them....

Comment: Most Guitars that I am familiar with have a set number of strings, 6. There are exceptions, notably a 12 string guitar, but my guess is that you can just set the Strings in the constructor to a constant. The same for guitar string names. Besides, you have the ui code in your getter methods which sorry to say is plum crazy. Just don't do that.

Comment: @user2557648 I would recommend you to check the current accepted answer.

Comment: @user2557648, hi, I just looked at my answer again, and admit that my answer was not correct. Look better at milesmas answer and I urge you to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one major problem - the direction shouldn't be from `Guitar` to `GuitarTest` but reversed - from `GuitarTest` to `Guitar` (because you use `Guitar` in tests). Also you have forgotten the argument of GuitarTest.main (obvious so not very important).

@milesma points out in the comment that I was initially incorrect and I agree with him:

> GuitarTest indeed used Guitar, but that is "Dependency" relationship.
>   (draw dashed line from Client to Supplier, in this example, from
>   GuitarTest to Guitar, which means, if Guitar changed, GuitarTest must
>   change); However, I don't think use Guitar in the function body is a
>   dependency. (If Guitar is used as method's parameter, return type etc,
>   then Dependency is guaranteed.). IMHO, there is no relationships
>   between.

Better check out @milesma answer which is more correct.

Comment: -1: Is not right. From the UML model, the `Guitar` class can navigate to `GuitarTest` class, which is wrong.

Comment: *you did it right from the UML point of view except one major problem*, I guess that's the whole point of the uml model...

Comment: @sasha.sochka, GuitarTest indeed used Guitar, but that is "Dependency" relationship. (draw dashed line from Client to Supplier, in this example, from GuitarTest to Guitar, which means, if Guitar changed, GuitarTest must change); However, I don't think use Guitar in the function body is a dependency. (If Guitar is used as method's parameter, return type etc, then Dependency is guaranteed.). IMHO, there is no relationships between.

Comment: @milesma, I wanted to delete this answer but I couldn't as it is accepted. I added your comment to the answer and I will ask the author now to mark your answer as accepted to delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

GuitarTest and Guitar classes should not have association relationship.

If you have a "GuitarCase" class, (and a "Cover" class)defined as follows:

```
public class GuitarCase{
    public Guitar g;
    public Cover  c = new Cover();
}
```

Then there should be an association from GuitarCase to Guitar, the association end (at the Guitar end) have role "g"; There should be a Composition from GuitarCase to Cover, the association end (At the cover end) have role "c";

I even prefer not to show the GuitarTest on the diagram because you can put the main function in Guitar itself.